# Opacity and Angular UI Dropdown Toggle

Tags: css, opacity, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a really annoying problem with opacity settings combined with Angular Ui Bootstrap. I have a table with a dropdown toggle in each row. When I hover over the rows, the opacity settings change on the one the mouse is currently on.
Here are my CSS settings:

```
tr {
zoom: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=70);
opacity: 0.7;
color: #292929;
}

tr:hover {
zoom: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
opacity: 1.0;
}
```

The dropdown toggle displays fine as long as I stay with the mouse on the menu. If I leave it, the dropdown-menu disappears behind the rows although in the CSS-settings the z-index for the dropdown-menu is set to 1000.

[mouse inside menu http://imageshack.us/a/img10/8536/okqi.jpg](http://imageshack.us/a/img10/8536/okqi.jpg)
mouse inside dropdown-menu

[mouse outside menu http://imageshack.us/a/img12/209/kipv.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img12/209/kipv.png)
mouse outside dropdown-menu

Any help or hint would be awesome!!!

Comment: I'd like you to try something: instead of applying your styles to `tr`, apply them to `td`. See what happens then. `tr` isn't really an element you can control with CSS. Try this.

Comment: I tried but it didn't solve my problem because now it didn't change the opacity of the background of the <tr> when i hover over it.